# Use awk to parse for vairable length

Tags: awk

I can't quite wrap my head around this one. I need to parse one or more lines on or after line 9, not including `""` or `,`.

So if the output is:

```
{
    "hash" : "000000000fe549a89848c76070d4132872cfb6efe5315d01d7ef77e4900f2d39",
    "confirmations" : 88029,
    "size" : 189,
    "height" : 227252,
    "version" : 2,
    "merkleroot" : "c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a",
    "tx" : [
        "c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a"
],
    "time" : 1398824312,
    "nonce" : 1883462912,
    "bits" : "1d00ffff",
    "difficulty" : 1.00000000,
    "chainwork" : "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000083ada4a4009841a",
    "previousblockhash" : "00000000c7f4990e6ebf71ad7e21a47131dfeb22c759505b3998d7a814c011df",
    "nextblockhash" : "00000000afe1928529ac766f1237657819a11cfcc8ca6d67f119e868ed5b6188"
    }
```

I want `c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a`.

Or if the output is:

```
{
    "hash" : "000000000fe549a89848c76070d4132872cfb6efe5315d01d7ef77e4900f2d39",
    "confirmations" : 88029,
    "size" : 189,
    "height" : 227252,
    "version" : 2,
    "merkleroot" : "c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a",
    "tx" : [
        "c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a",
        "c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a",
        "c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a"
    ],
    "time" : 1398824312,
    "nonce" : 1883462912,
    "bits" : "1d00ffff",
    "difficulty" : 1.00000000,
    "chainwork" : "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000083ada4a4009841a",
    "previousblockhash" : "00000000c7f4990e6ebf71ad7e21a47131dfeb22c759505b3998d7a814c011df",
    "nextblockhash" : "00000000afe1928529ac766f1237657819a11cfcc8ca6d67f119e868ed5b6188"
}
```

I want `c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a
c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a
c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a`.

The numbers will always appear at least on line 9, but may extend well beyond it.

Note that I used hash `c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a` for clarity. The hash will be unique each time (but will always be the same length).

I would prefer answers with actual awk. No gawk. No Perl.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: @DieterMeemken Nothing besides lots of searching. `I can't quite wrap my head around this one.`

Comment: You talk about "line 9" but it looks like you actually just want the value of the `tx` field. Is that right?

Comment: @EdMorton correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[[:space:]]*\]/ { inTx=0 }
inTx { gsub(/^[^"]*"|"[^"]*$/,""); print }
/^[[:space:]]*"tx"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*\[/ { inTx=1 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a
c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a
c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a
```

The above is just an implementation of the:

```
 awk '/end/{f=0} f{print} /start/{f=1}'
```

common awk idiom.

Comment: would +1 if I could. Counter-intuitive (for me).

Comment: Feel free to ask questions if you have any.

Comment: I believe this fails if the right square bracket (close-array) is on the same line as the data. This would be valid JSON, but would cause `inTx` to remain at `1` after the valid close of the array.

Comment: Yup if the input is different from what the OP posted then it would take a different script to parse it. I'm assuming the OP has a rigid format which is why he is looking for an awk rather than jq or similar solution. Note that the OP didn't mention JSON in his question or any of his comments - he just showed a block of text he needs to parse.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is complicated for you because you use the wrong tool. `awk` can't parse json, use `jq` for that:

```
jq -r .tx[] input.json
```

Comment: What does this return, precisely?

Comment: It does output what you wanted. The members of `.tx`

Comment: Can I pipe things into jq like with awk? `a.sh | jq -r .tx[]`?

Comment: Yes, why not trying it?

Answer (score 0):

another `awk` based on the input format

```
$ awk -F' +: +' 'NF!=1{p=0} p&&!/]/{gsub(/"|,/,""); print} $1~/"tx"/{p=1}' json

        c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a
```

and for the other input

```
$ awk ... json2

        c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a
        c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a
        c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a
```